# Laptop connecting to 802.11g or 802.11a instead of 802.11n or 802.11ac

Tags: windows, wireless-networking

I have a HP Probook 440 laptop, and a NETGEAR R7000 router. The laptop has the Intel 7265 wireless adapter. Now, both support b/g/n/ac. Still, the laptop is connecting using 802.11g protocol (as per task manager's wifi tab). I tried connecting to my iPad's hotspot, and it defaulted to 802.11n. My other computer is connecting to the same network using 802.11n. I then tried connecting to the 5ghz network on the router, which supports ac. It defaulted to 802.11a, instead of ac.
The router has no option to disable a/b/g and be n only or ac only.
What do I do?

Comment: Do you have TKIP encryption enabled on the router? Is so, the use of TKIP automatically disables the HT data rates (i.e. 802.11n/802.11ac).

Comment: I checked there, and it seems I have used AES only, not TKIP.

Comment: @YLearn Close but not quite. Having TKIP available is not a problem (it’s not needed, but it’s not a problem) the problem is if security is required but WPA2 (AES-CCMP) is not available. So if you have WPA2/WPA mixed mode enabled, HT and VHT will still work.

Comment: Just a thought, I’ve seen some shitty software call the 2.4GHz band “the B band” (or “the G band”) and call the 5GHz band “the A band”. Is there any chance the software you’re looking at is doing that, so not really saying you’re using G or A, but using it as a crappy way of denoting 2.4GHz vs 5GHz?

Comment: @Spiff, no, TKIP is the issue at hand. You can run WPA  with AES-CCMP with no problem if you wanted. The presence of TKIP is what causes the drop in data rates.

Comment: @Spiff If that were the case, shouldn't it show 802.11g for the iPad hotspot? It is showing 802.11n. Plus, task manager shows 802.11n on other computers on my home network.

Comment: @YLearn Just to be clear, WPA does not include AES-CCMP. The WFA defined WPA to only support TKIP. Any vendor that populates the WPA IE with AES-CCMP as a pairwise cipher is doing something nonstandard. Second, if you enable both WPA2 (an 802.11i RSN IE populated with AES-CCMP as the pairwise cipher), and WPA (a WPA IE populated with TKIP as the pairwise cipher), Wi-Fi compliant N and AC clients will successfully authenticate using WPA2 (AES-CCMP) and will successfully use N and AC rates. The Wi-Fi certification test plan specifically tests for this.

Comment: @Spiff, we are getting well beyond what comments are intended, but the WFA does not define the standard, rather it is the IEEE who maintains, creates and approves changes to the 802.11 standard. The WFA provide certification that a device adheres to (certain portion of) the standard to help assure interoperability and certification is only required if a vendor wants to use the Wi-FI logo. There are only very minor differences between WPA (draft 802.11i) and WPA2 (802.11i) and both can be used with either CCMP-AES (mandatory) or TKIP-RC4 (optional), although WFA only certified WPA with TKIP.

Comment: @YLearn WPA and WPA2 are both WFA standards, not IEEE. WPA2 is based on some elements of IEEE 802.11i, but WPA2 is not an IEEE standard. WPA2 and 802.11i are not synonymous, because WPA2 specifically forbids 802.11i's TSNs. And again, the presence of optional TKIP does not cause problems for N and AC clients, and the WFA's certification testing ensures that. The problem for N and AC clients is not the mere availability of optional TKIP, the problem is when security is required but AES-CCMP is not allowed.

Comment: @Spiff, no WPA and WPA2 are WFA definitions/certifications based on the IEEE 802.11i standard (see [here](https://goo.gl/KStL6J) and [here](https://goo.gl/be8P4Y) for WFA statements). As previously noted, most of the WFA certifications are based on devices adhering to certain portions of the IEEE standards. Yes, 802.11i provides for optional support of TSN, it is not required and is one of the features that WFA does not certify. 802.11n included the provision that any HT STA would eliminate TKIP as a choice, which also means the inverse of using TKIP as your encryption disables the use of HT.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have WPA2 and WMM enabled on both radios of the AP, and in the advanced driver properties of your client.

802.11n and 802.11ac require WMM, and either WPA2 or no security at all (WEP and original WPA/TKIP rely on RC4 stream cipher engines that are too slow to keep up with 802.11n/ac data rates).

If WMM and WPA2 (or no security) are not available, clients are not supposed to try to connect using 802.11n or 802.11ac.

Comment: I checked the settings, and WMM and WPA2 are on for both APs. I couldn't find the WMM setting for the laptop, even in the advanced menu. It still connected to 802.11g.